# Separate grid rows by field value

Tags: views

I have a custom content type with fields in which I collect, among others things, country. I'm using Drupal 8. I'd like to create a grid view page (using Views) of the content that is separated by country like shown in the image.

I'd like to avoid creating mupltiple views, one for each country, and then collating them into yet another page.

Any suggestions on how to make it happen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Grouping by a Field

Grouping by Fields is a standard feature in Views.

1. Create your Content Views with Page Display
2. Add the Country Field (Probably a Taxonomy term reference, there are ways to import country lists BTW)
3. Set `Format` to **Grid** and set **Number of columns**
4. In `Format` `Settings` set **Grouping field Nr.1** to your Country field

   Check in Preview that things look the way you want.
5. Edit the Country field and set it to **Exclude from display** because you have it output above each result group, your probably don't want it in each grid cell too
6. Edit the Country field `Style settings` if you want more control over how the "group headings" are output, but this works only in certain cases: D7 [How to change the HTML wrapped around a grouping output (HTML h3 tag)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1383696), D8 [Allow to configure the h3 element for view style plugins](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1880100), although you can use `Custom text` field for more control too.

Comment: Thanks, prkos! This worked! Yes, countries a taxonomy term.

Comment: Multiple entries under the country are stacked on top of one another rather than in columns though even though I selected 3 columns in the Grid Format setting. Bug? I'll see if I can fix it using CSS.

Comment: I tried it and the grid is displaying without problems. Does it look the same in the admin theme and also with your default theme when you visit the Views page? If you know CSS then you'll be able to debug what went wrong. Are you sure the grid template is being used and correct CSS styles are applied?

Comment: Thanks again for your time, prkos! Your comment made me take another look at the field re-write option I was using and I had an orphan <div> in there, which was throwing everything off.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm glad you worked it out in the end :)