# How to make one view with different taxonomy terms in different rows?

Tags: views, theming, taxonomy-terms

I want to make a view with 3 rows of lets say fruits, with 6 fruits max for each row. Spring, Summer and Autumn fruits.

And I don't want them to be mixed in one array so I could style them in view-template. How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post this as a comment but my rep is not high enough. I had asked a similar question and received an answer here: [Separate grid rows by field value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272922/separate-grid-rows-by-field-value/272968#272968)

Comment: Looks good but it doesn't give me 6 for each taxonomy term. My general number of elements that are displayed is 18. Do you know how to make it?

Comment: In Views, under Format, select Grid for Format and specify 6 for "Number of columns." That  doesn't work? Sorry, I'm an amateur at Drupal myself.